# Removing wipers arms from Megane Hatch 1.6e MK1

Tags: windshield-wipers, renault

I want to remove the wiper arms from a Renault Megane '98 hatch 1.6e engine. So far I tried opening the protection cap and unscrewing the nut from the bolt that the arm is attached to. I expected this to be enough, but the arms don't really loosened or moved after. They're either stuck to the metal or there is another trick to it. Has anyone done this, so they can confirm which one is it?

Also I'm trying to remove the wiper arms to replace the cabin ventilation fan/engine under them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the nut off of the wiper arm, you may need a small puller to get the arm off. These have a splined mount with an interference, which means, as you tighten them down they become more tightly wedged onto the mount. By using a puller, it should pop right off. The puller used for these have long thin puller arms, so not like a puller you'd have for pulling gears off. It might look something like this:

[image: Image From Amazon.com]

It can also look something like this:

[image: Image from Amazon.com]

Comment: Of course there is a tool for this! :)

Thanks!